Reference for the Sobolev $L^2$ trace lemma for an arbitrary line $C\subset \mathbb R^d$?
I am trying to find a reference for the following Lemma found in a paper:
Let $g\in H^s(\mathbb R^d)$ with $s>\frac{d-1}{2}$ and $C\subset\mathbb R^d$ be an arbitrary straight line. Then, there holds$$
            \|{g}\|_{L^2(C)}\lesssim_{s,d}\|{g}\|_{H^s(\mathbb R^d)}.
        $$
All the textbooks I have looked in e.g. Evans require the line $C$ to be bounded.

Can you edit your question to include the link to the paper
